# How to search a database using GPS information?

Tags: php, mysql, database, gps, geolocation

I'm collecting a list of businesses and with that information I'm collecting street addresses, city, state, zip, etc. I want to build an app that can accept search input of an address or use the device/browser's GPS or IP to generate one and then find businesses in my database within a certain geographic range.

My question is how I can (a) either create or access a database of geographic data I can use to search against and (b) How do I store data in such a way as to limit by, say, miles?  So that I can say "These businesses are within 30 miles of you, and you're 2.8 miles away from this one".

I know that Google Maps provides an API but reading through the documentation it appears I'd have to show that data on a map and that's not really within the scope of what I'm trying to do.  I want to present this data in the form of a list.

EDIT:

So with the termination that I need lat/long and some calculations.  How do I take an address say "123 whatever street Kansas City, Missouri" and turn that into LAT LONG I can store?

Comment: you don't store "distance". you store the lat/long, and then compute distances on the fly: `select id, .... where distance_calc($user_lat, $user_long) < $limit`

Comment: Convert your zip/post codes to coordinates, and then use Pythagoras' theorem to determine distance from the current point.

Comment: Marc B, excellent that's awesome.  I've edited the question with some follow up but I'll also ask here.  How do I take a user's address and convert that into lat/long in such a way that I'll be able to store it in a database?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to go to Microsoft SQL Server, they introduced `geography` column type in SQL 2008. There are built in database operations to do look ups on this data from lat/lon

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx

Otherwise, what you need to do, when you input an address or other type of data into your database is to geolocate it, probably using an external mapping API, such as http://api.mygeoposition.com/geopicker/